# Add new database option for reactive microservice

Tags: jhipster

when I create one reactive microservice, I need to add another database choise (like cassandra) but I can't customize blueprint for this specific question (I see only MongoDb right now)
How can I do it? Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add more choices into Microservice Reactive Blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230223/add-more-choices-into-microservice-reactive-blueprint)