# Add more choices into Microservice Reactive Blueprint

Tags: jhipster, reactive

when I create one reactive microservice, I need to add another database choise (like cassandra) but I can't customize blueprint for this specific question (I see only MongoDb right now)
How can I do it? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The experimental `Reactive` option only has support for MongoDB at this time (v5.3.1).  You can track the progress in the related issue, ["Reactive/Webflux support"](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7608)